# Does this database design fulfill 2NF or 3NF?

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, database-normalization

Ok so i have 2 tables. First table's name is `owner` with

```
owner_id primary key
first_name
last_name
```

and i have another table `car` with

```
car_reg_no primary key
car_type
car_make
car_model
car_origin
owner_id foreign key
```

Is this design in 2NF or 3NF or neither ?

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 3NF means its in 2NF and there are no [transitive functional dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency). In a slightly more understandable terms: "all attributes depend on key, whole key, and nothing but the key".

The first table fulfills all that, so it's in 3NF.

The second table needs some analysis: are there functional dependencies on non-keys? Specifically, can there be the same car model belonging to a different make?

- If yes, then the functional dependency `car_model` -> `car_make` **does not exist**, and the table is in 3NF (unless some other dependency violates 3NF - see the comment on `car_origin` below).
- It no, then there there is `car_model` -> `car_make` which violates 3NF.

Also, what's the meaning of `car_origin`? If it functionally depends on a non-key, this could also violate the 3NF.

Comment: No 2 cars made by different manufacturers can not have same model.So i guess it violates 3NF.

Comment: @SomeBody Yup, that would mean it violates 3NF.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, 2NF, due to interdependence of the fields of the `car` table. You would need a third table for `car_type` which lists make, model and origin, and a foreign `car_type_id` in the `car` table.

Comment: I agree car type data will be duplicated

Comment: Normalization doesn't have anything to do with adding surrogate id numbers.

Comment: @Catcall: no, but it does have something to do with duplication of data. The new field is just means to an end.